# Cracking the Coding Interview 6th Edition: 10.10. Rank from Stream

Tags: algorithm, stream, binary-search-tree

The problem statement is as follows:

> Imagine you are reading in a stream of integers. Periodically, you
> wish to be able to look up the rank of a number x (the number of
> values less than or equal to x). Implement the data structures and
> algorithms to support these operations.That is, implement the method
> track (in t x), which is called when each number is generated, and the
> method getRankOfNumber(int x) , which returns the number of values
> less than or equal to X (not including x itself).
>
> EXAMPLE: Stream(in order of appearance): 5, 1, 4, 4, 5, 9, 7, 13, 3
>
> getRankOfNumber(1) = 0 getRankOfNumber(3) = 1  getRankOfNumber(4) = 3

The suggested solution uses a modified Binary Search Tree, where each node stores stores the number of nodes to the left of that node. The time complexity for both methods is is O(logN) for balanced tree and O(N) for unbalanced tree, where N is the number of nodes.

But how can we construct a balanced BST from a stream of random integers? Won't the tree become unbalanced in due time if we keep on adding to the same tree and the root is not the median? Shouldn't the worst case complexity be O(N) for this solution (in which case a HashMap with O(1) and O(N) for track() and getRankOfNumber() respectively would be better)?

Comment: You can create a balanced binary tree with O(log n) insertion. Look at [AVL tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree), for example.

Comment: Thanks @JimMischel. But would you agree a simple BST won't remain balanced in most cases in this scenario?

Comment: No, I won't agree to that at all. Your worst case scenario only happens if the stream of numbers is presented in a particularly bad order. If the numbers are distributed so that they're not in any particular order, the tree should remain reasonably balanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to build an AVL or Red-Black Tree to have the O(lg n) complexities you desire.

about the rank, its kind of simple. Let's call count(T) the number of elements of a tree with root T.

- the rank of a node N will be:

  - firstly there will be `count(N's left subtree)` nodes before N (elements smaller than N)
  - let A = N's father. If N is right son of A, then there will be `1 + count(A's left subtree)` nodes before N
  - if A is right son of some B, then there will be `1 + count(B's left subtree)` nodes before N
  - recursively, run all the way up until you reach the root or until the node you are in isn't someone's right son.

as the height of a balanced tree is at most lg(n), this method will take O(lg n) to return you someone's rank ( O(lg n) to find + O(lg n) to run back and measure the rank ), but this taking in consideration that all nodes store the sizes of their left and right subtrees.

hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Building a Binary Search Tree (BST) using the stream of numbers should be easier to imagine. All the values less than the node, goes to the left and all the values greater than the node, goes to the right.
Then Rank of any x will be number of nodes in left subtree of that node with value x.

Operations to be done: Find the node with Value x O(logN) + Count Nodes of left Subtree of node found O(logN) = Total O(logN + logN) = O(logN)

In case to optimize searching of counts of node of left subtree from O(logN) to O(1), you can keep another class variable 'leftSubTreeSize' in Node class, and populate it during insertion of a node.